# Browser opens then closes prior to Ruby Script failing

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, browser, watir

All ruby test scripts have this same issue.

Once the Browser opens, it closes after 22 seconds and prior to the rest of the test script running. Below is the function that fails after `b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`. All the scripts were running without issues 3 weeks ago. Now none will advance pass `b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`.

```
def startBrowser

time0 = Time.new
  b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

  b.goto "https://test.mtc.byu.edu/assessmenttools/"

  if browser.title == "Assessment Tools"
    puts "Assessment Tools".yellow
    return browser
  else
    browser.close()
    return nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the version of chromedriver and/or selenium-webdriver are not compatible with the new version of Chrome.

Try:

1. [Update your chromedriver to the latest version](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), which is currently 2.9.
2. Update your selenium-webdriver to the latest version, which is currently 2.39.0 - `gem install selenium-webdriver`

Answer (score 0):

It seems it the same bug as [Chromedriver crashes when lauched from watir-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766804/chromedriver-crashes-when-lauched-from-watir-webdriver)

It is due to a childprocess issue ( https://github.com/jarib/childprocess/issues/71#issuecomment-35094547 )