# Chromedriver crashes when lauched from watir-webdriver

Tags: watir

I have the following gems and I also have the latest Chrome driver 2.9 version.

```
builder (2.1.2) 
bundler (1.6.0.pre.2) 
childprocess (0.4.1) 
coderay (1.1.0)
cucumber (0.8.7)
data_magic (0.17)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
faker (1.2.0)
ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
gherkin (2.1.4 i386-mingw32)
i18n (0.6.9)
json_pure (1.4.6)
method_source (0.8.2)
multi_json (1.8.4)
page-object (0.9.6)
page_navigation (0.9)
pry (0.9.12.6 i386-mingw32)
rubyzip (1.1.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.39.0)
slop (3.4.7)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
trollop (1.16.2)
watir-webdriver (0.6.7)
websocket (1.0.7)
win32console (1.3.2 x86-mingw32)
yml_reader (0.2)
```

I am not able to launch chrome through Watir-Webdriver. It launches a new window and crashes.

[image]
Not sure what is going wrong. Any suggestions?

```
irb(main):002:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):003:0>  browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
[8056:5984:0213/155207:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(332)] Failed to launch child process
[8056:1304:0213/155207:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8056:1304:0213/155207:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(332)] Failed to launch child     process
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(332)] Failed to launch child process
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(332)] Failed to launch child process
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(332)] Failed to launch child process
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:child_process_launcher.cc(332)] Failed to launch child process
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8056:1304:0213/155208:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[8056:1304:0213/155216:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.6.232923,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:99:in `create_session'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.7/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from (irb):3:in `new'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):004:0> exit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a issue related to the childprocess gem.

revert the gem to 0.3.9 should resolve this problem